# How to pass the value of inside a function a global variable in a class in Swift?

Tags: swift

I would like to store the value inside the function to the global variable inside the class.
I believe the problem might be with optionals.
Because it seems that the value is just stored inside the function but not outside. (Inside the funcntion the value is not nil, outside is nil)
I would appreciate any kind of help :)

Here is the code:

```
class PinterestCell: UICollectionViewCell {
 
    
    //I want to store the value inside the function here ..
    var imageViewHeightLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint

    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
            super.apply(layoutAttributes)
            if let attributes = layoutAttributes as? PinterestLayoutAttributes {
                //How can I pass the following value to the property imageViewHeightLAyoutConstraint
                    imageViewHeightLayoutConstraint.constant = attributes.imageHeight
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: What makes you believe it is not working?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you getting some kind of error when you try to do this? You can check if the problem is with optionals by putting a ```print()``` statement in the ```if let``` statement and see if it triggers. If it doesn't then you will know that the value is nil.

Comment: That's the problem, inisde the fucntion the value is not nil, but outside the function is nil.

Comment: "global variable inside the class" is an oxymoron. `imageViewHeightLayoutConstraint` isn't global. It's not scoped to the global scope, it's scoped to instance of the class. Thus, it's an instance variable.